Stronger statement of Abel's test?
I was thinking of Abel's test, and I kind of figured out a "better" criteria for showing the convergence of $\sum a_nb_n$.
We recall the proof of Abel's test, which uses summation by parts formula"
$$\sum_{k=1}^n a_nb_n = a_nB_n-\sum_{k = 1}^{n-1}B_k(a_{k+1}-a_k)$$
And Abel's test claims if $\left\{ a_n \right\}$ is monotone and bounded and $\sum b_n$ converges, then the original series converges. This can be easily proven by considering $\sum_{k = 1}^{n-1}B_k(a_{k+1}-a_k)$ monotone and bounded. However, I was thinking if we only have $\left\{ a_n \right\}$ converges, we can still show the origin series converges with ratio comparison test since,
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{a_nb_n}{Lb_n} = 1,\ L:=\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n$$
And $\sum Lb_n$ must converge since it's just a scalar multiplication of $\sum b_n$.
What might be my problem? Is there any counterexamples?

The ratio test does not apply here (it proves convergence of $\sum c_n$ only when $\lim_{n \to \infty} \left\lvert \frac{c_{n+1}}{c_n} \right\rvert < 1$).
As a counterexample take $a_n = b_n = (-1)^n\frac{1}{\sqrt n}$.
$\sum b_n$ converges because it is an alternating series such that $(\lvert b_n \rvert)$ is monotonically decreasing and converges to $0$.
Clearly $(a_n)$ converges to $0$.
However, the series $\sum a_nb_n = \sum \frac 1 n$ diverges.
